# Android emulator not loading an app

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Whenever I try to run an app on the Android emulator, from the eclipse in the adt bundle, the emulator loads and the console outputs this:

```
[2013-06-18 06:34:02 - Counter] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-06-18 06:34:02 - Counter] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-06-18 06:34:02 - Counter] Performing sync
[2013-06-18 06:34:02 - Counter] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Anroid_emulator'
[2013-06-18 06:34:02 - Counter] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Anroid_emulator'
[2013-06-18 06:34:03 - Counter] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-18 06:34:03 - Counter] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-06-18 06:34:37 - Counter] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-18 06:34:37 - Counter] Uploading Counter.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-18 06:34:37 - Counter] Installing Counter.apk...
[2013-06-18 06:35:12 - Counter] Success!
[2013-06-18 06:35:12 - Counter] \Counter\bin\Counter.apk installed on device
[2013-06-18 06:35:12 - Counter] Done!
```

Comment: Can you post your mainfest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked whether your app has been installed or not by going inside the menu?

Because if you have forgotten to make your activity as the launcher activity, your app will not pop up and you may not notice that your app has already been installed.

You can make that activity as launcher in the manifest by the below given tags:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you seem to be missing these in your manifest XML for the Activity that is the app's primary:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

For example, if your main activity is called `MainActivity`, it should look like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FooDzines" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ....
    ....
</application>
```